# Any tips on improving multiline regex?

Tags: php, regex

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/H4lBlG/1) works like it is supposed to, but maybe it's possible to make it a bit better?

```
<tr class="KNap"><td align="left">(.*)<\/td><td><a.*\n.*\n.*\n.*id" value="(.*)"><input type="hidden" name="sh" value="(.*)"
```

The regex works, but as you can see it has a pretty large amount of steps. (In this case 21837.)

Comment: Yes, dont use a regex, use a parser.

Comment: "Any tips" is too broad. Though less greedy and more specific matches (`\d+` or `\w+`) in place of `.*` would avoid most backtracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, make yourself comfortable with a parser and xpath queries.
For your specific example this could be:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($your_html_here, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

# KKom
$text = $xpath->query("//tr[@class='KNap']/td/text()")->item(0)->textContent;

$form = $xpath->query("//tr[@class='KKom']//form")->item(0);
$id = $xpath->query("input[@name='id']", $form)->item(0)->getAttribute("value");
$sh = $xpath->query("input[@name='sh']", $form)->item(0)->getAttribute("value");

echo "$text, $id, $sh";
```

---

Which yields

```
Re: Zero Kara Hajimeru Isekai Seikatsu ep01, 60564, c0daea22d108b4d6888f6037623b61d505d5b345
```